# python selenium text copy

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently making a bot that automates my projects with selenium and python but I want to copy the remote from the GitHub repo and copy it in my clipboard, **Is it possible to achieve this without GitHub API**

*This is the command lines I am talking about*--> https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIvej.jpg

I have removed my email address and password for obvious reasons

This is the code

````
import keyboard
import time
from selenium import webdriver

projectName = input("Enter your project name: ")
time.sleep(2)

os.startfile(
    'C:\\Users\\91730\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\System Tools\\Command Prompt'
)
time.sleep(2)
keyboard.write('cd C:\\Users\\91730\\Documents\\Projects\\Python')
keyboard.press_and_release('enter')

time.sleep(2)

keyboard.write('mkdir ' + projectName)
keyboard.press_and_release('enter')

time.sleep(2)

keyboard.write('cd ' + projectName)
keyboard.press_and_release('enter')

print("Made a folder called " + projectName + " and cd'ed into it :)")
time.sleep(2)

# Selenium automation STARTS here

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://github.com/login')

usernameInput = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_field"]')
usernameInput.click()
usernameInput.send_keys('#')

passwordInput = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
passwordInput.click()
passwordInput.send_keys('#')

submitBtn = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="login"]/form/div[4]/input[12]')
submitBtn.click()

newBtn = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="repos-container"]/h2/a')
newBtn.click()

repoName = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="repository_name"]')
repoName.send_keys(projectName)

crtRepo = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="new_repository"]/div[4]/button')
crtRepo.click()```
````

Answer (score 0):

With `driver.current_url()` you get the current url of the page.

Practically, you can get the text of any element by appending `.text` to a webdriver element you've already found with `find_element()`.

If you're interested in copy/paste, there is a cross-platform Python module for copy and paste clipboard functions: **pyperclip**.

Pypi link [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/).